# Where is the error in my LaTeX codes?

Tags: errors, code, conversion, mathjax

I use [rogercortesi.com](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/index.php?filename=tempimagedir%2Feqn9023.png&latextext=%5CDelta%20%3D%5Cbegin%7Bvmatrix%7D%20%0D%0A%20%201%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%20%20%26%5Cdots%20%20%26%201%20%20%20%20%20%5C%5C%0D%0A%20%201%20%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%20%20%26%5Cdots%20%20%26%201%20%20%20%20%5C%5C%0D%0A%20%201%20%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%20%20%26%5Cdots%20%20%26%201%20%20%20%20%20%5C%5C%0D%0A%20%201%20%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%20%20%26%5Cdots%20%20%26%201%20%20%20%20%20%5C%5C%0D%0A%20%20%20%5Cvdots%20%20%20%20%26%5Cvdots%20%20%20%20%20%26%5Cvdots%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%5Cvdots%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%5Cddots%20%26%5Cvdots%20%5C%5C%20%20%0D%0A%201%20%261%20%261%20%261%20%26%5Cdots%20%20%261%20%20%20%20%5C%5C%0D%0A%5Cend%7Bvmatrix%7D%20&outtype=png&bgcolor=white&txcolor=black&res=100&antialias=1) to convert LaTeX codes into images. But the code I wrote below doesn't work. I couldn't understand why. But the same code works very well [here.](https://arachnoid.com/latex/?equ=%5CDelta%20%3D%5Cbegin%7Bvmatrix%7D%20%0A%20%201%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%20%20%26%5Cdots%20%20%26%201%20%20%20%20%20%5C%5C%0A%20%201%20%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%20%20%26%5Cdots%20%20%26%201%20%20%20%20%5C%5C%0A%20%201%20%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%20%20%26%5Cdots%20%20%26%201%20%20%20%20%20%5C%5C%0A%20%201%20%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%261%20%20%20%20%20%26%5Cdots%20%20%26%201%20%20%20%20%20%5C%5C%0A%20%20%20%5Cvdots%20%20%20%20%26%5Cvdots%20%20%20%20%20%26%5Cvdots%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%5Cvdots%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%5Cddots%20%26%5Cvdots%20%5C%5C%20%20%0A%201%20%261%20%261%20%261%20%26%5Cdots%20%20%261%20%20%20%20%5C%5C%0A%5Cend%7Bvmatrix%7D%20) What is the cause of the problem? Here are codes:

```latex
\Delta =\begin{vmatrix} 
  1          &1   &1            &1     &\dots  & 1     \\
  1    &1    &1   &1     &\dots  & 1    \\
  1    &1    &1   &1     &\dots  & 1     \\
  1    &1    &1   &1     &\dots  & 1     \\
   \vdots    &\vdots     &\vdots      &\vdots      &\ddots &\vdots \\  
 1 &1 &1 &1 &\dots  &1    \\
\end{vmatrix}
```

Comment: “Doesn't work” in what sense? I get the expected image. Anyway, this is off-topic as the sites you mention don't use TeX, but MathJax.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document beginning with `\documentclas` and ending with `\end{document}`. Showed code fragment doesn't contain any error.

Comment: I am new. I will try to fix my mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that while there are several potential reasons for why you're getting errors messages, there are *two leading reasons*:

- You failed to embed the expression in a *math group* -- either inline math or display math.
- You failed to load the `amsmath` package, which provides the code for the `vmatrix` environment you employ.

To wit, the following code compiles fine as a LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'vmatrix' environment
\begin{document}
\[ % initiate an unnumbered displaymath group
\Delta =\begin{vmatrix} 
  1      &1      &1      &1      &\dots  & 1     \\
  1      &1      &1      &1      &\dots  & 1     \\
  1      &1      &1      &1      &\dots  & 1     \\
  1      &1      &1      &1      &\dots  & 1     \\
  \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\  
  1      &1      &1      &1      &\dots  &1
\end{vmatrix} 
\] % terminate the displaymath group
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question: To create the same output *without* employing a `vmatrix` environment, one could write:

```
\[
\Delta =\left\vert \begin{array}{@{} *{6}{c} @{}}
  1      &1      &1      &1      &\dots  & 1     \\
  1      &1      &1      &1      &\dots  & 1     \\
  1      &1      &1      &1      &\dots  & 1     \\
  1      &1      &1      &1      &\dots  & 1     \\
  \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
  1      &1      &1      &1      &\dots  &1      
\end{array} \right\vert
\]
```

i.e., one would replace `\begin{vmatrix}` with `\left\vert \begin{array}{@{}*{6}{c}@{}}` and `\end{vmatrix}` with `\end{array} \right\vert`.

---

*Second Addendum*: My default browser, Firefox (current version: 70.0.1), displays the following screen when I try to visit rogercortesi.com. I think I'll stay away from this site!

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to write this codes in a different way?   I'm trying to convert it to a picture https://www.rogercortesi.com. But I can not.

Comment: @Elementary - I'm afraid I'm absolutely unfamiliar with the website you mention. I've posted an addendum to show how one might create the exact same output but without using a `vmatrix` environment.

Comment: Thank you very much. This definitely works.

Comment: Ohh, my yandex browser show the same warning I hope nothing happens to me..

Comment: If you're worried about that you should just look a bit into (La)TeX. I think I read that you can compile .tex files directly into .png's if that's what you need. Then you won't have to worry about dodgy sites and you can use one of the provided solutions.

Comment: Following your visit, it turned into a HTTP site which says "This is a test" and "Hello world" :)

Comment: Currently, if I go to the unencrypted site, it works, but if I go to the encrypted site, it claims that the TLS certificate says `phpwebhosting.com`, not `rogercortesi.com`. So it’s a configuration error and the webmaster should get a new cert.

Answer (score 4):

You might have forgotten to `\usepackage{amsmath}` which provides the necessary functions you are using.

I'll post an example where I got it to work - you have to enable math mode as well to access/use these functions (I think? I'm quite new to this as well).

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \[ %enters math mode
    \Delta=\begin{vmatrix}
                1          &1   &1            &1     &\dots  & 1     \\
                1    &1    &1   &1     &\dots  & 1    \\
                1    &1    &1   &1     &\dots  & 1     \\
                1    &1    &1   &1     &\dots  & 1     \\
                \vdots    &\vdots     &\vdots      &\vdots      &\ddots &\vdots \\
                1 &1 &1 &1 &\dots  &1    \\
    \end{vmatrix}
    \]
\end{document}
```

I can not comment yet, but it would always be helpfulto add the errors you have been seeing in your question, so it's easier to find out what your problem might be. :)

Comment: I'm trying to convert it to a picture https://www.rogercortesi.com But my codes doesnt work.

Comment: Could you provide the error you are getting? What doesn't work in your code? What are your error messages? It's hard to figure out what your problem is without further information.

Comment: I think I misread the question. I mean, my code doesn't work on this site. But other codes are all working. https://www.rogercortesi.com/

Answer (score -1):

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}

```
        $\Delta$&=&\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
            1          &1   &1            &1     &$\dots$  & 1     \\
            
            
            1    &1    &1   &1     &$\dots$  & 1    \\
            1    &1    &1   &1     &$\dots$  & 1     \\
            1    &1    &1   &1     &$\dots $ & 1     \\
            $\vdots $   & $\vdots $    & $\vdots  $    &$\vdots$      &$\ddots$ &$\vdots$ \\
            1 &1 &1 &1 &$\dots$  &1    \\
        \end{tabular}
        \end{tabular}
        
        \vspace{2cm}
    
    
    
            \begin{tabular}{cc|c|}
                
                $\Delta$&=&\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
                    1          &1   &1            &1     &$\dots$  & 1     \\
                    
                    
                    1    &1    &1   &1     &$\dots$  & 1    \\
                    1    &1    &1   &1     &$\dots$  & 1     \\
                    1    &1    &1   &1     &$\dots $ & 1     \\
                    $\vdots $   & $\vdots $    & $\vdots  $    &$\vdots$      &$\ddots$ &$\vdots$ \\
                    1 &1 &1 &1 &$\dots$  &1    \\
                \end{tabular}
            \end{tabular}\\
            \vspace{1cm}\\
            This is simpler. One can change  the size by
             renewcommand   \{arraystretch\}
        \end{document}
```

Here the number of columns can be fixed by the user and one can put its  placement also. I could not run your code. It gave me the answer looked like infinite size.
Since we use tabular environment we can adjust the size of columns.

I think that you did not set the size of your vmatrix. Therefore, the answer looks different.

Comment: (i) please extend your code fragment to complete small document, (ii) add some explanation how your answer is related to OP problem, (iii) explain what is benefit of (to my opinion unnecessary complicated and bad looking) solution over solutions  suggested in other answers.

Comment: I tried to run your code. Finally I think I found the solution. If I run vmatrix normal way, it gives the error. If I put it in math mode with \[   delta= begin{vmatrix}  and with \end{vmatrix} and \]. it does not give any error. This answer is given by Jooler also. The idea given me is not to use packages when things are simpler.